# Unable to connect to SQL on aspnet_regsql.exe

Tags: security, forms-authentication, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a standalone environment, and I am trying to configure FBA on my local machine, I ran `aspnet_regsql.exe,` and it said it's `unable to connect to SQL`.

The account am using is the sp_admin account that I've used to install SharePoint, not the sp_farm account.

I checked the permissions on SQL, and `under security > Logins > sp_admin`, I can see that in the server roles, the account has these permissions: `dbcreator, securityadmin, public, sysadmin.`

Is there a reason why I can't connect to SQL?

Comment: Go to Network Configuration in Configuration Manager

Enable TCP/IP

Enable Named Pipes

Comment: @PranavPatel The problem doesn't have anything to do with pipes, it's login failed when accessing SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your SQL Server instance definitely accessible over named pipes? By default, SQL Server is locked down quite tightly these days, so you may need to enable named pipes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342308/running-aspnet-regsql-exe-error

Also check [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44538f5f-2a99-4c72-9e83-c05d9d5d084b/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-using-the-aspnetregsqlexe?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

Comment: Hi Waqas, It's a standalone machine, so SQL is installed on the same box as SharePoint. Also I have tried with the SQL Account, and I am getting the same error, the tool can't access SQL, although I can open SQL management studio with both users.

Comment: Also the errors you have mentioned talk about named pipes, I am not getting this error, I am getting failed to login for this user.